Trying to get the CodiumAI plug in to work in IntelliJ
I have the CodiumAI plugin installed, but I am only seeing what appears to be the Codiumate Tests.
Am I missing something?
I have my program in the middle screen.  Codiumate is in the right third of the screen.  I am trying to get to someplace that can write code for me.
Can figure out how to get there.

This tutorial can help you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
